# What is the difference between the regex (.*?) and (.*)?

Tags: regex

I've been doing regex for a while but I'm not an expert on the subtleties of what particular rules do, I've always done `(.*?)` for matching, but with restriction, as in I understood it would stop the first chance it got, whereas `(.*)?` would continue and be more greedy.

but I have no real reason why I think that, I just think it because I read it once upon a time.

now I'd like to know, is there a difference? and if so, what is it...

Comment: `?` is quiet redundant! cuz any way `(.*)` would match 0 to many characters..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(.*?)` is a group containing a non-greedy match.

`(.*)?` is an optional group containing a greedy match.

Comment: so you're saying that (1) means, THERE IS a group, just non-greedy and (2) means THERE MAYBE A group, meaning it might not return anything.

so since I'm always using (1), I'm basically demanding that it finds something, in a non greedy fashion, which could explain why sometimes the regex fails to hit something, because I'm demanding at least one match.  is that right?

Comment: @ChristopherThomas: No, because `.*?` can also match nothing.

Comment: can you explain the difference between greedy and non-greedy?

Answer (score 7):

Others have pointed out the difference between greedy and non-greedy matches.  Here is an example of different results you can see in practice.  Since regular expressions are often embedded in a host language, I'm going to use Perl as the host.  In Perl, enclosing matches in parenthesis assigns the results of those matches to special variables. Therefore in this case, the matches may be the same but what's assigned to those variables may not:

For example, let's say your match string is 'hello'.  Both patterns would match it, but the matched portions ($1) differ:

```
'hello' =~ /(.*?)l/;
# $1 == 'he' 

'hello' =~ /(.*)?l/;
# $1 == 'hel'
```

Comment: The difference is that `?)` defines a non-greedy quantifier which means that the matches will not be the same. Of course `)?` is non-matching as you mentioned, but that's not a full answer.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you mean here.....could you explain it a different way? thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 6):

Because `*` means "zero or more", it all gets slightly confusing. Both `?`'s are quite different, which can be more clearly shown with a different example of each:

`fo*?` will match only `f` if you supply it `foo`. That is, this `?` makes the match non-greedy. Removing it makes it match `foo`.

`fo?` will match `f`, but also `fo`. That is, this `?` makes the match optional: the part that it applies to (in this case only `o`) must be present 0 or 1 times. Removing it makes the match required: it must then be present exactly once, so only `fo` will still match.

And while we're at different meanings of the `?` in regexps, there's one more: a `?` immediately following a `(` is a prefix for several special operations, such as lookaround. That is, its meaning is not like any of the things you ask.

Answer (score 5):

The `?` has different meanings.

1. When it follows a character or a group it is a quantifier, matching 0 or 1 occurrence of the preceding construct. [See here for details](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)
2. When it follows a quantifier it modifies the matching behaviour of that quantifier, making it match lazy/ungreedy. [See here for details](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: so in (1), it means it'll return something, but could be an empty string? is an empty string a valid return for a regex, I thought no, but I'm seeing it that way now

Comment: If you allow the pattern to match an empty string, then it is a valid return. A pattern `.*` makes only sense as a subpattern, otherwise it makes no sense, cause it matches everything. If you want to match at least one character, then `.+` would be correct choice, it matches One or more. Maybe you are interested in a blog post I wrote: [You do know Quantifiers. Really?](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-H)

Comment: Hi Stema, loved your article, found it really useful, plus the extra link to the re.info website about "repititions"  What I've learned from that is that the .*? form is saying, match what you can, as lazily as you can, so that kind of makes sense, it's the minimum number of matches, including zero/empty.  So that would explain why it works in my examples and uses.