# Java Regular Expression repeated group capture

Tags: java, regex

I am getting problem capturing a repeated group here, Can anyone help?

String : Ushinski K. D. (Konstantin Dmitrievich)

The regex I'm using is this :

```
(?i)(.*)((?:[a-z]{1,2}\.\s)+)\(.*
```

But it is capturing `"Ushinski K. "` as group 1 and `"D. "` as group 2. However my target is to capture `"Ushinski "` as group 1 and `"K. D. "` as group 2. Any help is highly appreciated.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQ9E0I/1)

Comment: It's  a problem of quantifier greediness, not a problem or repeated group.

Comment: You might also want to include your Java code.

Comment: I have updated with the regex101 portal link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `(.*?)` or you can use [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `(\b.*\b)` instead of `(.*)` take a look at this post [What is the difference between the regex (.*?) and (.*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705478/what-is-the-difference-between-the-regex-and)

```
(?i)(.*?)\s((?:[a-z]{1,2}\.\s)+)\(.*
```

or

```
(?i)(\b.*\b)\s((?:[a-z]{1,2}\.\s)+)\(.*
```

#### regex demo 1

#### regex demo 2

Comment: very interesting, could you also explain why? ( I really want to know)

Comment: i will explain @nafas

Comment: no problem, i can't add more than that post @nafas you can anderstand what is the deffirence between `(.*) and (.*?)`

Comment: @YCF_L How using reluctant quantifier solved the issue?

Comment: @user3345621 check the link *YCF_L* provided, it'll explain the difference between greedy and lazy matching.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'first name' has no space :

```
(?i)(\S*)\s*((?:[a-z]{1,2}\.\s)+)\(.*
```

I advice you to use this website for your regular expressions : https://regex101.com/

**edit** : if it has space but no '.':

```
(?i)([^\.]+)\s+((?:[a-z]{1,2}\.\s)+)\(.*
```

Comment: No there is nothing specified as that. Actually the requirement is to capture consecutive initials in a String